# Holes in polygon on OSM

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I recently upgraded from 3.05 to 4.2 in open street maps for Android where i used to initialize my mapview using the code below

```
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
```

This used to work fine in the 3.x version of osm library for android but the tiles wont load in the 4.2 one. In LogCat i go those 2 errors but i do not know if there are relevant with osm.

1

```
  03-23 20:44:35.773: I/o*.o*.v*.MapView(9397): Using tile source: org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource@428fabb0
03-23 20:44:35.773: I/AndroidLoggerFactory(9397): Logger name 'org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBase' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'o*.o*.t*.MapTileProvid*' instead.
03-23 20:44:35.773: I/AndroidLoggerFactory(9397): Logger name 'org.osmdroid.tileprovider.LRUMapTileCache' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'o*.o*.t*.LRUMapTileCac*' instead.
03-23 20:44:35.773: I/AndroidLoggerFactory(9397): Logger name 'org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.TileWriter' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'o*.o*.t*.m*.TileWriter' instead.
03-23 20:44:35.773: I/AndroidLoggerFactory(9397): Logger name 'org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileModuleProviderBase' exceeds maximum length of 23 characters, using 'o*.o*.t*.m*.MapTileMod*' instead.
03-23 20:44:35.773: E/File(9397): fail readDirectory() errno=13
```

2.

```
03-23 20:44:44.083: I/System.out(9397): downloader calls detatch()
03-23 20:44:44.103: I/System.out(9397): downloader calls detatch()
03-23 20:44:44.583: W/System.err(9397): [DEBUG] GbaRequest - GbaRequest: Constructor Called 222 userAgent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
03-23 20:44:44.583: W/System.err(9397): [DEBUG] NafRequest - NafRequest: NafRequest constructor===useragent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
03-23 20:44:44.603: W/System.err(9397): [DEBUG] GbaRequest - GbaRequest: Constructor Called 222 userAgent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
03-23 20:44:44.603: W/System.err(9397): [DEBUG] NafRequest - NafRequest: NafRequest constructor===useragent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
```

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: The name of the library is *osmdroid* and not *osm library for android*. Please try to be as precise as possible when asking questions, there are various other OSM libraries available for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. i had to add the write_external_storage and read_external_storage permissions so the osm can download the tiles.